# Update the date of a datetime object when using datetime.addhours(-1)

Tags: c#

I have an datetime object that I want to remove one hour to display the corect time in a different time zone.  I am using datetime.addhours(-1) with the -1 being a config value.  This works in most cases except when I set the time to 12:59 AM today it displays 11:59 AM today. When it should display 11:59 PM. Is it possible to have addDays() repect the date?

Comment: Please post a demonstration program or a piece of code that demonstrates the problem. It's not that I don't believe you but I am unable to reproduce this problem, and DateTime produces the right value in all cases I've ever tried with additions and subtractions.

Comment: I just tried tjhis, and I am getting exactly what you expect... not what you say you are experiencing.. I am using VS2005 on an XP machine... 2.x CLR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the Subtract function:

```
DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
```

Comment: Not sure how this could be the best answer when clearly the .AddHours(-1) method works just fine.

Comment: I don't recall any datetime related changes between frameworks. How could .Subtract( new TimeSpan( 1, 0, 0 )) be faster, better, or even clearer to read than .AddHours( -1 )

Comment: I was also puzzled by the original question - just presenting an alternative approach here.

Answer (score 2):

There's a method that can help you with timezones:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(..)
```

[Linkage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttime.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I notice you didn't specify which framework version you are using.  If you are using 2.0 SP1, 3.0 SP1, or 3.5 SP1 you might want to use the [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) structure instead.  Then you would simply specify the Timezone offset and everything should work.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, if you are handling time zone issues you should use the functions that store the datetime in a UTC format and then map to the correct TZ.

However if that is overkill for your application what you are doing is correect.

```
DateTime datetime = new DateTime( 2008,12,17,0,59, 0 );
datetime = datetime.AddHours(-1);
```

This results in a time of 23:59:00 or 11:59PM on 12/16/2008.

The time you are feeding in might not have the proper am/pm designator.